# What if there was no baryon-antibaryon asymmetry in our universe?

Tags: cosmology, radiation, dark-energy, matter, baryons

We know that the universe goes through different evolutionary phases: radiation, matter and later dark energy epoch.

What would happen if there was no baryon-antibaryon asymmetry? How would the evolutionary phases change? Would their period lengths be changed and why?

Answer (score 0):

This is the [timeline in the mainstream](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html) Big Bang model.

[image]

The baryon asymmetry is still an open question, a research topic, as far as the standard model of physics.

There are extensions of the model that break the symmetry at [baryogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis) time. This happens at $10^{-11}$ in [the plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe#Baryogenesis). , by the time of quark confinement which will decide the number of baryons and antibaryons.

Here [is a review](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2013.00033/full) of the research that connects it with dark matter.

> The nature of dark matter and the origin of the baryon asymmetry are two of the deepest mysteries of modern particle physics. In the absence of hints regarding a possible solution to these mysteries, many approaches have been developed to tackle them simultaneously leading to very diverse and rich models. We give a short review where we describe the general features of some of these models and an overview on the general problem. We also propose a diagrammatic notation to label the different models.

After quark confinement there should be equal numbers of baryon and antibaryon galaxies.In general there are no observations of equal baryons and antibaryons, so a model has to be decided on by research. This, depending on the model, would lead to a different timing for the ending of the universe, one would not haveto wait for protons to decay.